# C# WinForm - SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics draw 2D Texture

Tags: c#, winforms, sharpdx, slimdx

I would like to implement hardware acceleration for a C # WinForms application. Reason is that i have to draw 150 x 720p images and the 5 picturebox control's takes too long (scaling+drawing of images) and therefore are problems with disposing and reloading.
So I dealt with ShapeDX.

But now I 'm stuck and do not know how to draw the 2D Texture. To test the code i just have a Test Button and one PictureBox.

When I run the code in the PictureBox also DirectX ( Draw or 3D ) is loaded. I acknowledge the black background. **But I do not understand how the Texture must be drawn.**

```
        String imageFile = "Image.JPG";

        Control TargetControl = this.pictureBoxCurrentFrameL;
        int TotalWidth = TargetControl.Width;
        int TotalHeight = TargetControl.Height;

        SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device defaultDevice = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device(SharpDX.Direct3D.DriverType.Hardware, SharpDX.Direct3D11.DeviceCreationFlags.Debug);

        SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice = SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.New(defaultDevice);
        SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.PresentationParameters presentationParameters = new SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.PresentationParameters();
        presentationParameters.DeviceWindowHandle = this.pictureBoxCurrentFrameL.Handle;
        presentationParameters.BackBufferWidth = TotalWidth;
        presentationParameters.BackBufferHeight = TotalHeight;

        SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.SwapChainGraphicsPresenter swapChainGraphicsPresenter = new SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.SwapChainGraphicsPresenter(graphicsDevice, presentationParameters);
        SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.Texture2D texture2D = SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.Texture2D.Load(graphicsDevice, imageFile);

        //Now i should draw. But how?

        swapChainGraphicsPresenter.Present();/**/
```

Using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 (.Net 4, C# WinForm) on Windows 10 an SharpDX-SDK-2.6.3!

Thank you for assistance.

Comment: How often do you need to update your UI? How many times per second? You might want to just use GDI.

Comment: I get up to 150x 720p frames per second . is 5x different sources ( 30 fps ).  
  
2x 720p video ( 30 fps )  
2x 720p video frames ( with recognized patterns )  
1x 720p video frames with final result  
  
Pattern recognition is divided into several threads. The final calculation is also performed on a separate thread.  
  
All images are generated from different threads and are asynchronous.

Comment: I tested GDI today. apparently the performance is similar to controls. I think using GDI is better than controls. so you can control the drawing (eg drop frames, dispose, etc) , but I would prefer to use Direct Draw .

Can someone help me with the Direct Draw problem?

Comment: Does somebody has any idea?

Comment: If you're only drawing 2D stuff you should use Direct2D.  I'm pretty sure SharpDX wraps it.  DirectDraw has been marked as deprecated for about ten years now.  The way you are using it is not how I have done it in the past.  And its implementation is not trivial, so I don't know that including all of my code here is appropriate.  I'll see if I can put something together, but it might be a while. There should be a Direct2D sample with SharpDX. Try that then let me know if you need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by simply switching to SlimDX (SlimDX Runtime .NET 4.0 x64 January 2012.msi, .Net4, Win10, MS Visual Studio Community 2015, Winforms App.). There are several useful tutorials .

to use SlimDX just link the only one DLL to ur project! after installing SlimDX u will find this SlimDX.dll file somewhere on ur C Drive.

it is important to understand that you need at least one factory and an render target for Direct2D . The RenderTarget points to the object to be used ( Control / form / etc ) and takes over the drawing.

a swap chain is not needed. probable used by the render target internally. the biggest part is to convert an bitmap into usefull Direct2D Bitmap (for drawing). Otherwise, you can process the bitmap data also from a MemoryStream .

For Those Who are looking for a solution too:

```
        Control targetControl = this.pictureBoxCurrentFrameL;
        String imageFile = "Image.JPG";

        //Update control styles, works for forms, not for controls. I solve this later otherwise .
        //this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        //this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
        //this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);

        //Get requested debug level
        SlimDX.Direct2D.DebugLevel debugLevel = SlimDX.Direct2D.DebugLevel.None;

        //Resources for Direct2D rendering
        SlimDX.Direct2D.Factory d2dFactory = new SlimDX.Direct2D.Factory(SlimDX.Direct2D.FactoryType.Multithreaded, debugLevel);

        //Create the render target
        SlimDX.Direct2D.WindowRenderTarget d2dWindowRenderTarget = new SlimDX.Direct2D.WindowRenderTarget(d2dFactory, new SlimDX.Direct2D.WindowRenderTargetProperties() {
            Handle = targetControl.Handle,
            PixelSize = targetControl.Size,
            PresentOptions = SlimDX.Direct2D.PresentOptions.Immediately
        });

        //Paint!
        d2dWindowRenderTarget.BeginDraw();
        d2dWindowRenderTarget.Clear(new SlimDX.Color4(Color.LightSteelBlue));

        //Convert System.Drawing.Bitmap into SlimDX.Direct2D.Bitmap!
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)Properties.Resources.Image_720p;//loaded from embedded resource, can be changed to Bitmap.FromFile(imageFile); to load from hdd!
        SlimDX.Direct2D.Bitmap d2dBitmap = null;
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), bitmap.Size), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);//TODO: PixelFormat is very important!!! Check!
        SlimDX.DataStream dataStream = new SlimDX.DataStream(bitmapData.Scan0, bitmapData.Stride * bitmapData.Height, true, false);
        SlimDX.Direct2D.PixelFormat d2dPixelFormat = new SlimDX.Direct2D.PixelFormat(SlimDX.DXGI.Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm, SlimDX.Direct2D.AlphaMode.Premultiplied);
        SlimDX.Direct2D.BitmapProperties d2dBitmapProperties = new SlimDX.Direct2D.BitmapProperties();
        d2dBitmapProperties.PixelFormat = d2dPixelFormat;
        d2dBitmap = new SlimDX.Direct2D.Bitmap(d2dWindowRenderTarget, new Size(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), dataStream, bitmapData.Stride, d2dBitmapProperties);
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

        //Draw SlimDX.Direct2D.Bitmap
        d2dWindowRenderTarget.DrawBitmap(d2dBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));/**/

        d2dWindowRenderTarget.EndDraw();

        //Dispose everything u dont need anymore.
        //bitmap.Dispose();//......
```

So it is super simple to use Direct2D, all the code can be compressed to 2 main Lines + drawing:

```
        SlimDX.Direct2D.Factory d2dFactory = new SlimDX.Direct2D.Factory(SlimDX.Direct2D.FactoryType.Multithreaded, SlimDX.Direct2D.DebugLevel.None);
        SlimDX.Direct2D.WindowRenderTarget d2dWindowRenderTarget = new SlimDX.Direct2D.WindowRenderTarget(d2dFactory, new SlimDX.Direct2D.WindowRenderTargetProperties() { Handle = targetControl.Handle, PixelSize = targetControl.Size, PresentOptions = SlimDX.Direct2D.PresentOptions.Immediately });

        d2dWindowRenderTarget.BeginDraw();
        d2dWindowRenderTarget.Clear(new SlimDX.Color4(Color.LightSteelBlue));
        d2dWindowRenderTarget.DrawRectangle(new SlimDX.Direct2D.SolidColorBrush(d2dWindowRenderTarget, new SlimDX.Color4(Color.Red)), new Rectangle(20,20, targetControl.Width-40, targetControl.Height-40));
        d2dWindowRenderTarget.EndDraw();
```